# Batch write from to Kafka does not observe checkpoints and writes duplicates

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks

Follow-up from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765133/writing-large-dataframe-from-pyspark-to-kafka-runs-into-timeout): I'm writing a large dataframe in a batch from Databricks to Kafka. This generally works fine now. However, some times there are some errors (mostly timeouts). Retrying kicks in and processing will start over again. But this does not seem to observe the checkpoint, which results in duplicates being written to the Kafka sink.

So should checkpoints work in batch-writing mode at all? Or I am missing something?

Config:

```
EH_SASL = 'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=****";'

dfKafka \
.write  \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net:9093") \
.option("topic", "mytopic") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/telemetry/cp.txt") \
.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark checkpoints tend to cause duplicates . Storing and reading Offset from Zookeeper may solve this issue. Here is the link for details :

http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/05/07/spark-kafka-achieving-zero-data-loss.html

Also, in your case , checkpoints are not working at all or checkpoints are causing duplicates ? Above URL help is for the later case.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps in my case. I'm not reading from Kafka, but writing to it. So I somehow would need to store which rows from my dataframe I have already written out. I thought checkpointing would do that, but to your question: I don't know if it is working at all, hence my question here.

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoints are not available in the batch mode, but you can use streaming with the `.trigger(once=True)` or `.trigger(availableNow=True)` trigger to benefit from  the checkpointing and have batch-like writing in Spark.