# How to format a pyspark connection string for Azure Eventhub with Kafka

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am trying to parse JSON messages with Pyspark from an Azure Eventhub with enabled Kafka compatibility. I can't find any documentation on how to establish the connection.

```py
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

sc.stop() # Jupyter somehow created a context already.. 
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonTest")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

# my connection string: 
#Endpoint=sb://example.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=examplekeyname;SharedAccessKey=HERETHEJEY=;EntityPath=examplepathname - has a total of 5 partitions

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(HOW DO I STRUCTURE THIS??)
parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))
parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Messages in this batch: %s' % x).pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer (and question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023607/1537195). That was for how to write to an Kafka-enabled Event Hub in pyspark but I assume reading config should be pretty similar. The tricky part was to get the security configuration right.

```
EH_SASL = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=****";'
// Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/spark#running-spark

dfKafka \
.write  \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
.option("kafka.batch.size", 5000) \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myeventhub.servicebus.windows.net:9093") \
.option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000) \
.option("topic", "raw") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/telemetry/cp.txt") \
.save()
```

You can find any official tutorial on how to set up a consumer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/blob/master/tutorials/spark/sparkConsumer.scala). It's for Scala instead of PySpark but it's fairly easy to transform the code if you compare it with my example.

Comment: Hello @silent! I am sorry, I am not 100% clear on it. Where would this be in my above example to read the stream? Where is dfKafka defined?

Comment: I have added a link to an official tutorial. That should get you started

Comment: It doesn't find: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule so it complains about most of the options. I coded a C# example yesterday and it took 10 minutes. Is Pyspark some edge case?

Comment: ah sorry, my code was for running on Databricks. Try this one: `org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule` I'll update my answer

Comment: Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-397550fbfd5d> in <module>
     29   .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "30000") \
     30   .option("kafka.group.id", "example") \
---> 31   .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
     32   .load()

Comment: It finds none of the options. Perhaps some import missing? It seems not to be a part of any of these:  azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.13.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.3.jar,spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3.jar,kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Have you looked at the link? https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/spark#running-spark "connecting Spark with Event Hubs using the native Spark Kafka connector requires Apache Kafka v2.0+ and Apache Spark v2.4+."